# If my input is over multiple lines, I need the output to also be over multiple lines

Tags: c++

I have created a program that reverses the letters in every word in a sentence. I am inputting text into an input text file over 4 lines. The output text is all on 1 line but I need it to be so that when the input goes to the next line, so does the output.

```cpp
string reversed(string word)
{
    int n;

    for(int i=0; i<word.length()/2; i++)
    {
        swap(word[i],word[word.length()-1-i]);
    }

    return word;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;

    in.open("input.txt");
    out.open("output.txt");

    string word;

    while(in>>word){
        out << reversed(word) << " ";
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Example of input:

```
Expecting the world to treat you
fairly because you are a good person
is a little like expecting the bull not to
attack you because you are a vegetarian.
```

Example of output:

```
gnitcepxE eht dlrow ot taert uoy
ylriaf esuaceb uoy era a doog nosrep
si a elttil ekil gnitcepxe eht llub ton ot
kcatta uoy esuaceb uoy era a nairategev.
```

Comment: could you give an example of input and output please?

Comment: Luckily for you, the `>>` operator leaves any delimiting whitespace in the stream. How can you take advantage of that to figure out whether you need to start a new line in your output?

Comment: If you want to account for *lines* you need to read *lines*. `operator>>` ignores lines. You may want to investigate functions that have the word "line" in their name.

Comment: @OznOg, I have added an example of an input and required output

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::getline()` to read individual lines of text from the input, and then use a `std::istringstream` to iterate through the individual words of each line:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string reversed(std::string word) {
    std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
    return word;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    std::string line, word;

    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> word) {
            out << reversed(word);
            while (iss >> word) {
                out << " " << reversed(word);
            }
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/AGEtME)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many possible solutions. I will show you one piece of code which makes heavy use of the std library and hence ends up in just a few lines of code. The interesting work will be done in just 3 statements of code in function main. No loop structure like `do`, `while`, `for` or other control structures are needed.

This is more of a modern C++ style.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

struct WordsInLine  // The words in one line + proxy for output iterator
{
    std::vector<std::string> wordsInLine;   // Container for words in one line

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const WordsInLine& w) { 
        std::copy(
            w.wordsInLine.begin(), w.wordsInLine.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{os, " "}); 
        return os; 
    }
};

// Make reading easier
using AllLines = std::vector<WordsInLine>;

struct Line      // ! This is a proxy for the input_iterator ! 
{   // Input function. Read on line of text file and split it
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Line& line) { 
        std::string wholeLine;
        std::regex space("[ \\.\\,]");
        line.words.wordsInLine.clear();
        std::getline(is, wholeLine);    // Read one complete line and split it into parts
        std::copy(
            std::sregex_token_iterator(wholeLine.begin(), wholeLine.end(), space, -1),
            std::sregex_token_iterator(),
            std::back_inserter(line.words.wordsInLine)
        );
        return is;
    }

    operator WordsInLine() const { return words; }  // cast to needed result
    WordsInLine words;  // Local storage for all words in line
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFileStream{ "r:\\input.txt" };      // Open input file. Will be closed by destructor
    std::ofstream outFileStream{ "r:\\output.txt" };    // Open output file. Will be closed by destructor

    // 1. Read complete input file into memory and organize it in words by lines
    AllLines allLines{ std::istream_iterator<Line>(inFileStream), std::istream_iterator<Line>() };

    // 2. For all lines: Reverse all words in a line
    std::for_each(
        allLines.begin(), allLines.end(),
        [](WordsInLine& w) {
            std::for_each(
                w.wordsInLine.begin(), w.wordsInLine.end(),
                [](std::string& s) { std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end()); }
            );
        }
    );

    // 3. Output result to file
    std::copy(
        allLines.begin(), allLines.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<WordsInLine>{outFileStream, "\n"}
    );

    return 0;
}
```

I use a proxy for the input and the output iterators. The input iterator additionally parses the line and extracts all words. Please note: with the regex, I do additionally eliminate "." and "," in the parsed words.

The reverse operation is achieved by nested `std::for_each()` and nested lambdas.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that avoids the use of regex can simply reverse each word (and if desired, `.find_first_of()` containing a list of punctuation and `.erase()` from that position). A fairly straight-forward approach would be to read each line with `getline` and then create a `stringstream` from the line and then read each word from the `stringstream`, outputting to your output file. A simple flag can be used to control space addition between each word.

A short implementation without punctuation removal could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse (const std::string& s)
{
    return std::string (s.rbegin(), s.rend());
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string line;   /* string to hold each line */

    if (argc < 3) {     /* validate 2 arguments given */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input.\nusage: ifile ofile\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream ifs {argv[1]};        /* open input file */
    std::ofstream ofs {argv[2]};        /* open output file */

    while (getline (ifs, line)) {       /* read each line */
        std::istringstream ss {line};   /* create stringstream from line */
        std::string word;               /* string to hold word */
        size_t wc = 0;                  /* flag to control space output */
        while (ss >> word)              /* read each word */
            ofs << (wc++ ? " " : "") << reverse (word); /* output rev'ed */
        ofs << '\n';    /* tidy up with newline */
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/words_reverse ../dat/captnjack.txt ../dat/captnjack_rev.txt
```

**Example Output File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack_rev.txt
sihT si a elat
fO niatpaC kcaJ worrapS
A etariP oS evarB
nO eht neveS .saeS
```

---

**Edit Based On Your Post Of Input/Output**

If you wanted to remove punctuation at the end of the words, you can do so with `.find_first_of()` and `.erase()`. Since you are now moving the punctuation to the end of the word where it was found, you need to save the character before you `.erase()` it from the word. You can then add it after the word. With punctuation removal and moving to the end of the word, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string reverse (const std::string& s)
{
    return std::string (s.rbegin(), s.rend());
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string line;   /* string to hold each line */
    const std::string rmchars {".,!?"}; /* punctuation to remove */

    if (argc < 3) {     /* validate 2 arguments given */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient input.\nusage: ifile ofile\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream ifs {argv[1]};        /* open input file */
    std::ofstream ofs {argv[2]};        /* open output file */

    while (getline (ifs, line)) {       /* read each line */
        std::istringstream ss {line};   /* create stringstream from line */
        std::string word;               /* string to hold word */
        size_t wc = 0;                  /* flag to control space output */
        while (ss >> word) {            /* read each word */
            size_t rmpos = word.find_first_of (rmchars);  /* index or npos */
            char punc = 0;              /* char to hold punctuation */
            if (rmpos != std::string::npos) { /* if not npos */
                punc = word[rmpos];     /* save punctuation char */
                word.erase (rmpos);     /* erase punctuation */
            }
            ofs << (wc++ ? " " : "") << reverse (word); /* output rev'ed */
            if (punc)
                ofs << (char)punc;      /* output punctuation char */
        }
        ofs << '\n';                    /* tidy up with newline */
    }
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/sentences.txt
Expecting the world to treat you
fairly because you are a good person
is a little like expecting the bull not to
attack you because you are a vegetarian.
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/words_reverse_w_punc dat/sentences.txt dat/sentences_rev.txt
```

**Example Output File**

```
$ cat dat/sentences_rev.txt
gnitcepxE eht dlrow ot taert uoy
ylriaf esuaceb uoy era a doog nosrep
si a elttil ekil gnitcepxe eht llub ton ot
kcatta uoy esuaceb uoy era a nairategev.
```

There are many ways to approach the problem. You can make it is easy or as complex as you need to.